# ¿Cómo modificar correctamente estos registros en archivo binario?

Tags: c, archivo, binario

Estoy haciendo un programa sobre un hospital, pero tengo un apartado donde tengo que modificar los datos de los pacientes en un archivo binario. Sin embargo, tengo dos problemas:

1. Cuando modifico el ID o la edad del paciente, que son datos enteros, no los procesa correctamente.
2. Cuando quiero desplegar la lista de pacientes otra vez, me sale el duplicado el registro.

Adjunto el código con el cual proceso un par de modificaciones (realmente el resto son parecidas) y el que me permite modificar valores que son int

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct paciente{ // Registro correspondiente a los datos de los pacientes
    int id;
    char nombre[16];
    char s_nombre[16];
    char apellidop[16];
    char apellidom[16];
    int edad;
    bool estatus=false; // 0 - Paciente internado || 1 - Paciente dado de alta
};

int Modificar_Pac(){
    FILE *pacientes_a;

    int id_consulta;
    int i=0, existencia=0, opcion_modificar;

    pacientes_a=fopen("pacientes.bin", "rb+");
    printf("Ingresar ID del paciente a modificar: ");
    scanf("%i", &id_consulta);
    struct paciente pacientes;

    if (pacientes_a==NULL){
        printf("No existe el pacientes_a, creando...\n\n");
        pacientes_a=fopen("pacientes.bin","ab");
        return 0;
    }

    if (pacientes_a){
        while(!feof(pacientes_a)){
            fread(&pacientes, sizeof(struct paciente), 1, pacientes_a);
            if (id_consulta==pacientes.id){
                printf("ID: %i\n", pacientes.id);
                printf("Nombre: %s  ", pacientes.nombre);
                if (strcmp(pacientes.s_nombre,"x")!=0) printf("%s", pacientes.s_nombre);
                printf("\nApellido paterno: %s\n", pacientes.apellidop);
                printf("Apellido materno: %s\n", pacientes.apellidom);
                printf("Edad: %i\n", pacientes.edad);
                printf("\n\n");


                printf("Que dato desea modificar?\n");
                printf("\t[1]: Nombre\n\t[2]: Segundo nombre\n\t[3]: Apellido Paterno\n\t[4]: Apellido Materno\n\t[5]: Edad\n\t[6]: ID del paciente\n\t[7]: Regresar al menu\n\n");

                scanf("%i", &opcion_modificar);
                switch (opcion_modificar){
                    case 1:{
                        rewind(pacientes_a);
                        printf("Nombre: %s\n\n", pacientes.nombre);
                        printf("Introduce el nuevo nombre: ");
                        scanf("%s", pacientes.nombre);
                        fseek(pacientes_a,ftell(pacientes_a)-sizeof(struct paciente),SEEK_SET);
                        fwrite(&pacientes, sizeof(struct paciente), 1, pacientes_a);
                        fclose(pacientes_a);
                        existencia=1;
                        system("clear");
                        return 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2:{
                        rewind(pacientes_a);
                        printf("Segundo nombre: %s\n\n", pacientes.s_nombre);
                        printf("Introduce el nuevo nombre: ");
                        scanf("%s", pacientes.s_nombre);
                        fseek(pacientes_a,ftell(pacientes_a)-sizeof(struct paciente),SEEK_SET);
                        fwrite(&pacientes, sizeof(struct paciente), 1, pacientes_a);
                        fclose(pacientes_a);
                        system("clear");
                        return 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    [...]
                    case 5:{
                        rewind(pacientes_a);
                        printf("Edad: %i\n", pacientes.edad);
                        printf("Introduce la nueva edad: ");
                        scanf("%i ",&pacientes.edad);
                        fseek(pacientes_a,ftell(pacientes_a)-sizeof(struct paciente),SEEK_SET);
                        fwrite(&pacientes, sizeof(struct paciente), 1, pacientes_a);
                        fclose(pacientes_a);
                        return 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    case 6:{
                        rewind(pacientes_a);
                        printf("ID del paciente: %i\n", pacientes.id);
                        printf("Introduce el nuevo ID: ");
                        scanf("%i", &pacientes.id);

                        if (pacientes_a){
                            fread(&pacientes, sizeof(struct paciente), 1, pacientes_a);
                            while(!feof(pacientes_a)){
                                if (id_consulta==pacientes.id){
                                    printf("El ID ya existe en el sistema, seleccionar otro");
                                    existencia=1;
                                    break;
                                    return 0;
                                }
                                fread(&pacientes, sizeof(struct paciente), 1, pacientes_a);
                            }
                        }
                        fseek(pacientes_a,ftell(pacientes_a)-sizeof(struct paciente),SEEK_SET);
                        fwrite(&pacientes, sizeof(struct paciente), 1, pacientes_a);
                        fclose(pacientes_a);
                        system("clear");
                        return 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    case 7:{
                        return 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    default:{
                        printf("Dato invalido");
                        return 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                while (opcion_modificar!=7);
                existencia=1;
                break;
                }
            }
            if (existencia==0) printf("El paciente no existe en el sistema\n\n");
        }
    fclose(pacientes_a);
    return 0;
}
```

Adjunto la función con la que hago esas modificaciones.

[image: Resultado antes de modificar a un paciente]

[image: Resultado despues de agregarle un segundo nombre al paciente]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Posicionas el cursor del archivo al inicio del mismo
rewind(pacientes_a); 

printf("Edad: %i\n", pacientes.edad);
printf("Introduce la nueva edad: ");
scanf("%i ",&pacientes.edad);

// Estamos al inicio del archivo... intentas posicionarte en una posición negativa!!!
fseek(pacientes_a,ftell(pacientes_a)-sizeof(struct paciente),SEEK_SET); 

// Escribes algo en alguna parte ... no sabes cual
fwrite(&pacientes, sizeof(struct paciente), 1, pacientes_a);
```

No puedo probar tu código, pero diría que eliminando la instrucción `rewind` de cada `case` debería funcionar

Quizás, por legibilidad, mantenimiento y sentido común, deberías centralizar la escritura del archivo y no repetirla en cada `case`:

```
int modificar = 0;

switch (opcion_modificar){
case 1:
    printf("Nombre: %s\n\n", pacientes.nombre);
    printf("Introduce el nuevo nombre: ");
    scanf("%s", pacientes.nombre);
    modificar=1;
    break;

case 2:
    printf("Segundo nombre: %s\n\n", pacientes.s_nombre);
    printf("Introduce el nuevo nombre: ");
    scanf("%s", pacientes.s_nombre);
    modificar=1;
    break;

// ...

default:
    printf("Dato invalido");
    break;
}

if( modificar == 1 )
{
    fseek(pacientes_a,ftell(pacientes_a)-sizeof(struct paciente),SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&pacientes, sizeof(struct paciente), 1, pacientes_a);
}
fclose(pacientes_a);
```

Comment: Toda la razón!! Eliminando el rewind, ya comenzó a funcionar mejor; sin embargo, sí tuve que dejar el fseek y el fwrite en cada case porque si lo dejaba en general para todo, no modificaba la informacion:( Y aun tengo dudas del por qué se cicla el programa cuando modifico datos que son int:( Aún así muchisimas gracias!